# how to get in between year and month where From year and month To month year using sql

Tags: sql-server

```
MonthFROM  |  YearFROM  |  MonthTo | YearTO
---------------------------------------------
   02          2012          05       2012
```

Output Should be:

```
Month  Year
 02    2012
 03    2012
 04    2012
 05    2012
```

Comment: You can use CTE with recursion

Comment: Yes, google "Recursive CTE" and you will find examples.   You can also write a WHILE loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using master..spt_values as tally table (maximum 2047 months otherwise use another tally table):

```
DECLARE
  @MonthFROM int = 2,
  @YearFROM  int = 2012, 
  @MonthTo   int = 5,
  @YearTO    int = 2012

DECLARE
  @from datetime = dateadd(month, @MonthFROM-1, cast(@YearFrom as char(4)))
DECLARE
  @to datetime = dateadd(month, @MonthTO-1, cast(@YearTo as char(4)))

SELECT month(dateadd(m, number, @from)) Month, year(dateadd(m, number, @from)) Year
FROM
   master..spt_values
WHERE 
  type = 'P' and
  number <= datediff(month, @from, @to)
```

Result:

```
Month Year
2     2012
3     2012
4     2012
5     2012
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) and convert your ranges to a datetime for easy handling.

```
declare @tab TABLE (ID int,MonthFROM int,  YearFROM  int,  MonthTo int, YearTO int)
insert into @tab Select 1,2,2012,5,2012


;With CTE(Start,aEND) as
(
Select CAST(
           CAST(YearFROM AS VARCHAR(4)) +
           RIGHT('0' + CAST(MonthFROM AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '01'   
           AS DATETIME) as Start
      ,CAST(
           CAST(YearTo AS VARCHAR(4)) +
           RIGHT('0' + CAST(MonthTo AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '01'   
           AS DATETIME) as aEND
from  @tab   
Where ID=1

UNION ALL
Select DATEADD(MM,1,Start),aEND from CTE  Where DATEADD(MM,1,Start)<=aEND                   

)
Select DATEPART(MM,Start) as [Month],DATEPART(YY,Start) as [Year] from CTE
```